# bootstrapping domains with eachWithIndex

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class

Another headache :-( Someone please help. I'm simply trying to batch create domain instances using `eachWithIndex` within my bootstrap file in my Grails 3 project.

Here's my domain class...

```
package ttt_server

class TttPriority {

    String name
    int order
    Date dateCreated

    static constraints = {
        name blank: false, nullable: false
        order blank: false, nullable: false
        dateCreated nullable:true, blank:true
    }

}
```

Here's my bootstrap code for batch creation...

```
["Mortal","Major","Critical","Minor","Nice To Have"].eachWithIndex{ name, idx ->
    new TttPriority(name: name, order: idx).save(flush:true)
}
```

I'm near to the point of pulling my hair out on this one.

Here's the error....

> 2017-07-31 16:30:41.755 ERROR --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order) values (0, 'Mortal', 0)' at line 1
>   2017-07-31 16:30:41.817 ERROR --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               >: Application startup failed
>
> org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: Hibernate operation: could not execute statement; bad SQL grammar [n/a]; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order) values (0, 'Mortal', 0)' at line 1
>       at ...

Comment: And that's why we should use ORMs... wait a minute! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because *order* is a reserved word you have to use some other name for your column. Or surround your column name with backticks

Example

```
static mapping = {
    order column: "order_col"
}
```

or

```
static mapping = {
    order column: "`order`"
}
```

Comment: You got in there first. This indeed was the problem. Should have been obvious to me. Thank you for all your help :-)

Answer (score 2):

`order` is a SQL keyword. You need to rename or remap that property.

```
static mapping = {
    order column: "my_order"
}
```